# How to pass async function to Pool.map()?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

The following code will get the error of

> multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[<coroutine object f at 0x000001EA90528CC0>]'. Reason: 'TypeError("cannot pickle 'coroutine' object")'

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

async def f(x):  # removing async works
    return x * x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(3) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1,2,3]))
```

How to use `Pool.map` with asynchronous function?

Comment: Why are you combining async tasks and multiprocessing like this? They are broadly two different ways of solving the same sort of problem.

Comment: Yes, I will need to use both of async (for non-block event loop for boto3) and partition (multiprocessing) for performance requirements.

Comment: The answer is you can't.  You can only tell multiprocessing to "run this (synchronous) method". That said, your synchronous method can call asynchronous methods if it wants, using the standard tools for setting up asynchrony.

Comment: Only way I can think of to mimic such is [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) - create multiple subprocess and awaiting for them to finish, which would create a lot more overhead (and more codes) - you might want to separate async part and sync part, maybe try producer-consumer pattern?